# Need to 'map' my array, from separete file [React+ ts]

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript

> Recently I've started to learn Typescript, and figured out that all my knowledge about JavaScript is blown away, because of more watching how to code instead of just coding.

I am using React with TypeScript + TailwindCss

So my question is how do I can 'map' my array, which is on sepate file?

**This is my component**

```
import { AiFillShop } from 'react-icons/ai'
import { navUrl } from '../interfaces/navurl';


const Header = () => {
    return (
        <header className='w-full shadow-md fixed top-0 left-0 max-w'>
            <div className='md:flex bg-purple-700 py-7 md:px-10 px-7'>
                <div className="leftNav font-bold text-2xl cursor-pointer flex items-center font-[Poppins] ">
                    Super Shop
                    <span className='ml-2 cursor-pointer'>
                        <AiFillShop/>
                    </span>
                </div>


                <ul className="">
                    
                </ul>
            </div>
        </header>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

I need to map next array into li elements

**This is my Array**

```
export const navUrl: { name: string; url: string }[] = [
    {
        name: 'HOME',
        url: '/',
    },
    {
        name: 'MISSION',
        url: '/',
    },
    {
        name: 'WARRANTY',
        url: '/',
    },
    {
        name: 'CONTACTS',
        url: '/',
    },
    {
        name: 'USED',
        url: '/',
    },
];
```

When I code this:

```
navUrl.map((link) => {
                    <li></li>
                    })
```

I have the error:

> webpack compiled with 1 error and 1 warning
> ERROR in src/components/Header.tsx:19:40
> TS1382: Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'>'}` or `&gt;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this should be in that `<ul>` element, the only changes I'm seeing to be made are:

1. Wrap the "code" part in `{}`
2. Return from the `.map()` callback (either explicitly with `return` in a function body or implicitly as a single-expression arrow function)
3. Add a `key` prop to the top-level element in the callback (*ideally* as a meaningful **unique** value from the array, such as an `id` property or something)

Minimal example:

```
<ul className="">
  { navUrl.map(link => <li key={link.name}></li>) }
</ul>
```

Or using values from the array elements:

```
<ul className="">
  { navUrl.map(link => <li key={link.name}>Name: {link.name}, URL: {link.url}</li>) }
</ul>
```

Or multiple lines in the return value (notice the parentheses that now wrap the `<li>` JSX element):

```
<ul className="">
  { navUrl.map(link => (
    <li key={link.name}>
      Name: {link.name}, URL: {link.url}
    </li>
  )) }
</ul>
```

Comment: Didn't you forget about keys? Maybe use `<li key={name}>`

Comment: @AgainPsychoX: Good catch, adding now...